# Is there a way to determine / specify what core an M1 MacOS program is running on?

Tags: macos, apple-m1

Scenario: I'm logging in remotely to my M1 Mini, and trying to run a Perl script which launches a long stream of instances of my (compiled for arm64 C++) program, one at a time, for testing purposes.  Because it will surely take hours to run the full sequence, I nohup the Perl script.

I launched the first test run about 36 hours ago, and it is about one-third completed thus far.  This is much slower than I'd expected -- in general my individual tests of the program have shown this machine to be faster than any other machine I have, and this isn't living up to that at all.

I got to thinking about this, and wondered if my code is getting treated as a "background" task, and run on one of the power-efficient "Icestorm" cores rather than one of the fast "Firestorm" cores.  Does anyone know how to detect which core a process is running on and/or control which core a process is run on?

Comment: If you suspect that it's the `nohup` that is causing it, what if you try running it inside a terminal multiplexer such as tmux or screen?

Comment: Good thought, there are a bunch of fairly obvious experiments I can try to see if I can indirectly get a handle on what is going on.  Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, while I'm still very interested to the answer to this question, I finally have the results of the test run in, and there's one portion of the code that performed extremely badly.  It looks strongly like I've got a corner of my C++ that wasn't as portable as I thought, and at a first guess it seems likely part of that was being much slower than it should have been.